# Problemas no menu do layout one page

Tags: javascript, html

Olá, estou desenvolvendo um layout one page, porém estou com problemas no menu, na navegação tenho links para divs na home, porém um único link no menu vai para outra página no site, e quando se está nessa página e clica em outro link de navegação, o script não encontra a div naquela página. O que eu preciso é que o script volte para a home e busque pela div lá.

**HTML:**

```
<nav class="desktop">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/cardapio">Cardápio</a></li>
        <li><a class="interno" href="#destaques">Destaques</a></li>
        <li><a class="interno" href="#galeria">Galeria</a></li>
        <li><a class="interno" href="#sobre">Sobre</a></li>
        <li><a class="interno" href="#contato">Contato</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$('.main-header .top-header nav.desktop ul li a.interno').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   var id = $(this).attr('href');
   targetOffset = $(id).offset().top,
      menuHeight = $('.main-header .top-header').innerHeight();
   $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: targetOffset - menuHeight
   }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: E porque nessa página separada vc não coloca os links completos, da mesma forma que fez para entrar nessa página extrar tipo /index ou /#destaques?

Comment: Tentei colocar /#destaques no href mas não funciona

Comment: Tenta href="/index.html#destaques" , se funcionar me fala que posto como resposta :)

Comment: Não funciona. :(

Comment: Funciona apenas sem o script, com o script não funciona

Comment: Isso acontece por causa dessa linha no seu script `e.preventDefault();` na pagina que está separada retire essa linha do JS se for possível, ou se nessa página vc não usar nada desse JS ele nem faz sentido estar na página, então vc não precisa indexa-lo nessa página e use os links como falei anteriormente...

Comment: Sim, funcionou sem a linha, porém fica mostrando a div na url do navegador, essa lista já esconde isso.

Comment: Outra coisa é que a tela pisca antes de rolar para a div, como se fosse ao topo da pagina e rapidamente rolasse para a div

Comment: Cara a dica era retirar o `e.preventDefault();`  apenas na página que não vai ter ancoras internas, e não no Script da página principal... Se é que esse é o seu caso, pois se vc tiver um script.js indexado na página é só não indexa-la na página que vai ter as ancoras. Assim nessa página vc pode usar os links como falei `href="/index.html#destaques" `